# django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader not working for Django app

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, django-settings

I have 2 VPS on digital ocean that are serving an app, and mydomain.com works on the first one. I need to set up a stage environment, and navigating I get:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
accounts/login.html
```

and cannot log in. My project is visible:

```
Python Path:    
['/home/django/bookmarks_tracker/bookmarks_tracker',
 '/home/django/bookmarks_tracker',
...
```

but the default filesystem loader for templates is broken:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/accounts/login.html (File does not exist)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/accounts/login.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bootstrapform/templates/accounts/login.html (File does not exist)
/home/django/bookmarks_tracker/helpdesk/templates/accounts/login.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/crispy_forms/templates/accounts/login.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_extensions/templates/accounts/login.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mptt/templates/accounts/login.html (File does not exist)
```

I did give it the default filesystem loader however, in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "helpdesk/templates"),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The structure of TEMPLATES is identical in my working VPS, and the django versions are also the same. What could cause this to look inside apps, but not the templates dir? Thank you